# Help with keeping long table continuous across pages

Tags: tables, tabularray, appendix, longtblr, tblr

I have a long table created using the `longtblr` environment from the tabularray package, which spans across 10 pages. Additionally, I have a smaller `tblr` table that needs to be placed at the bottom.

The issue I'm facing is that on the last page (page 10), the long table is split, and the small table is inserted in between, making the long table discontinuous. I've tried using the `\\*` command to prevent the long table from breaking at certain points, but the small table still gets inserted in between.

How can I ensure that the long table remains in one piece and that nothing gets inserted in between? Unfortunately, I'm unable to provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE).

I apologize for the delay. I have been working on creating a MWE. Although my actual document class is IEEEtran, I encountered some difficulties in creating the MWE with that class. As a temporary solution, I have used the article class for the MWE.
The two tables are meant to be placed at the bottom of the article on the last page in the appendix section.

[image]

```
% \documentclass{IEEEtran}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
    \begin{longtblr}[]{
    hlines,
    vlines,
    }
      a & b \\
      a & b \\
      a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
    \end{longtblr}
% second small table
 \adjustboxset{width=0.6\linewidth, valign=M}
 \begin{table*}
   \caption{This is a small table} \label{tab:label}
   \begin{tblr}{
       hlines,
       colsep=3pt,
       colspec= {c *{2}{X[c,m]} },
       rowsep = 3pt,
     }
No  &   A   &  $ABC$   \\
 1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            
                     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}  \\
 2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            
                     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}  \\
   \end{tblr}
 \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE which reproduce your problem. Does the second table has option for float placement?

Comment: MWE can  contain two page long dummy table. This should not be so hard to prepare. If you not provide a MWE, how can expect that we can do this without any information about your document. We don't know, what you  doing.

Comment: @Zarko I just updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear, why to long table, which follows command `\onecolumn`, is inserted float `figure*`, when document is still in one column mode. In this mode you can use simple `table` to which you add placement options. For example `[htb]`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\onecolumn
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {long table, span over two columns}
        ]{hlines,vlines,
          colspec = {XX}  
          }
      a & b \\
      a & b \\
      a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
    \end{longtblr}
% second small table
  \begin{table}[ht]
   \caption{This is a small table} \label{tab:label}
\adjustboxset{width=0.6\linewidth, valign=M}
   \begin{tblr}{
       hlines,
       colsep=3pt,
       colspec= {c *{2}{X[c,m]} },
       rowsep = 3pt,
     }
No  &   A   &  $ABC$   \\
 1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}

                     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}  \\
 2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}

                     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}  \\
   \end{tblr}
 \end{table}
 % \twocolumn ?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use of `table*` has sense, if article is back to two column mode. In this case, table will start on the top of the next page.

Comment: Thank you, it is now working. I had forgotten to remove `\onecolumn` since I had previously used it in a two-column document class.

Comment: @internet, if answer solve your problem, then you may consider to accept it :-)